# Php preg_replace, replace only a subtring of matched element

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

With preg_replace, I can replace a matched substring by another like this :

```
echo preg_replace("yellow", "blue", "sky is yellow");
// print "sky is blue"
```

But is it possible to replace only a substring in the search string by another string ?

By example, I would like change this text :

```
<a>foo</a>
<a class="changehere">foo</a>
<a>foo</a>
```

by

```
<a>foo</a>
<a class="changehere">FAA</a>
<a>foo</a>
```

I tried this :

```
echo preg_replace("@<a class="changehere">(foo)</a>@", "FAA", $text);
```

But the whole of the line is changed to FAA ...
How can I find a substring, depending of others char around, and replace only the substring ?

Thanks for help :) ! 
I Hope I'm clear

Comment: Don't use regex to search/modify HTML. Use `DOM`

Comment: Do you see the text color change in the code. That should have created an error

Comment: This is a simple example, I word with a big file and it's not a html/XML doc. But it contains tags

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not parsing HTML/XML using regex, you may use this regex:

```
php > $text = '<a class="changehere">FAA</a>';
php > echo preg_replace('@<a class="changehere">\Kfoo(?=</a>)@', "FAA", $text);
<a class="changehere">FAA</a>
```

**Details:**

- `\K`: resets all matched info
- `(?=</a>)`: Lookahead to assert we have `</a>` ahead of current position